# Is this a viable way to update multiple rows?

Tags: mysql

It is possible to insert multiple rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (...), (...), (...)...
```

But for updating rows by their ID, there is no such shortcut in the UPDATE syntax.

But what about this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, columns-to-update) VALUES (1, values), (2, values)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column=VALUES(column)...
```

Is this an effective way to update multiple rows in a single query? Or it is just better overall to issue multiple (up to the hundreds) of individial queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's a perfectly valid way to do multiple updates